# SSL requests are failing on WSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, curl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot use `git` or `curl` or `apt-get` or any tool that does SSL requests on WSL. This is the outcome:

**Git:**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/../some-repo.git
Cloning into 'some-repo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/../some-repo.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function
```

**Curl:**

```
$ curl https://google.com
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.com:443
```

Comment: This error was due to a connectivity issue in my WSL environment. I solved it by following this tuto : https://townsyio.medium.com/wsl2-how-to-fix-download-speed-3edb0c348e29